# Magento2 - Inventory source By Product Sku

Tags: magento2, cataloginventory

I am getting the product inventory source successfully below is my code.

```
 $sources = $this->getSourceItemsBySku->execute($sku);

 $array = [];

 foreach ($sources as  $index => $source) {

 $array[] = [
         'value' => $source->getSourceCode(),
         'label' => $source->getName()
      ];
 }
```

Here you can see in an array I am getting value and label like this its showing be value but Label values in null `$source->getName()` so how I can get source name.

Comment: Not able to get your point, Can you try one more time:)

Comment: i have checked code its just return source code not source value

Comment: Source value means you want to retrieve all qty's available in different source ?

Comment: no source name like wharehouse source name dropship soruce name

Answer (score 0):

You can get source lable/name by using `Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface`

You can try below, Its untested:)

```
$source = $this->sourceRepository->get('source_code');
$sourceName =  $source->getName();
```